# File name encoding at Knoppix

Tags: character-encoding, filenames

I am getting file list in my Java program using list() method of File class. When I run my program on Knoppix I get ???? instead of Cyrillic file names. It seems that problem is in knoppix, not java. I tried to use options for mounting file system, such as nls and iocharset, but it has no effect (or may be I use it in wrong way). Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is as you said with Knoppix. Probably you do not have Cyrillic font bundled, so there is no way to display these code points.

If you want to fix this, you will need fix distribution, as there is nothing wrong with the program. I am not sure if this is the question for https://serverfault.com/ or https://superuser.com/, but you can read their FAQ's and ask how to fix it there (probably you will need to re-create Knoppix distribution).